# Want to return an image everytime the function is run but it keeps giving me an error. What's wrong here?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, jsx

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import img1 from './images/download.png' 
 
> function image( ){
> return (
>     <img src={(img1)}/> 
>   )
> }

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          Welcome to your first website!
        </p>
        <Link value='Learn React!'/>
        <Link value='Another link!'/>
        </header>
        image();
    
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've tried different ways of importing the image but none of them seem to not give me errors. I'm still a beginner and just need to find a resolve to this. I apologize if this is a simple question

Comment: In JSX you'll need to write `{ image() }` to render the result of calling the function in the div

Comment: "*it keeps giving me an error.*" - **what** error?

Answer (score -1):

Your function needs to be in brackets:

```
...
  </header>
  {image()}
...
```

You can also just put the image url/path in the element.

`src="./images/download.png"`

or if you're looking for it to be more dynamic, assign the url/path to a variable and pass it into your function. OR just include the img element in your return html.

```
function image(src){
  return (
    <img src={src}/> 
  )
}
```

OR

```
...
  </header>
  <img src="./images/download.png" />
</div>
```

You can also, while assigning it to a variable, keep it dynamic by passing in the source down to the return html:

```
...
const src = './images/download.png'
return (
...
  </header>
  <img src={src} />
</div>
...
```

Could you explain further what errors you are getting?